# Update statement reading the entire table

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-update

I have a pretty big table where I want to update values in one specific column. I'm wondering if I should just rebuild the entire table or use update statement. What I don't understand is why reading the entire table (i.e `select *`) will process the same amount of data (env. 1TB) as running the update statement. Is this possible to run the update statement without reading the entire table?

```
select *
from `table` t WHERE
  date BETWEEN '2023-01-01'
    AND '2023-02-01'
```

=> This is processing 1TB

```
UPDATE
  `table` t
SET
  col = u.value
FROM (
    SELECT
     token,
     value
  FROM
     `trans-gate-265215.sm_shopify.orders`) u
  WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2023-01-01'
        AND '2023-02-01'
   AND
    t.key = u.token
 )
```

=> This is also processing 1TB

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a potential remedy:

Create a 'partition' on your tables for the column: date
and to make it more efficient add 'cluster by' on the column: token

With partition on the date column and with your 'where' condition, it won't read/scan the entire table.

Also, with token cluster, it will make your joins faster.

Documentation reference for adding partition: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#sql

Comment: I already have a partition and the update operation itself is not that long. My question is more about why is the update statement need to read the entire table when I'm actually interacting with only two columns.

Comment: There is a bug in "closing Parentheses" in your given update statement, that's a bit confusing. If you have 'where condition' outside of first closing parentheses and if you remove the second closing parentheses and if you have a partition on date and 'cluster by' on token column in your table 't', then I don't think 'billing bytes' in query execution details would result entire scan of the table 't'.